# Экономия памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, память

Изучаю экономию памяти. Очень часто пишут о слотах, сборщике мусора и необходимости создавать меньшее количество объектов. Реже о сериализации словарей в json, к примеру.
Однако наткнулся на весьма нетривиальные для меня примеры, который не могу понять.

Первый пример:

```
class Intern(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = key
        return key
   
tuple_intern = Intern()
t1 = tuple_intern['abc', 'def']
t2 = tuple_intern['abc', 'def']
t1 is t2
```

Второй пример:

```
intern_tuple = lru_cache(maxsize=256)(lambda x: x)
t1 = intern_tuple(('abc', 'def'))
t2 = intern_tuple(('abc', 'def'))
t1 is t2
```

Третий пример:

```
class Intern(dict):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.setdefault(args, args)
tuples = Intern()
t1 = tuples('abc', 'def')
t2 = tuples('abc', 'def')
t1 is t2
```

Был бы рад помощи в объяснении подобных примеров. Есть ли в них смысл?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

[Ссылка на источник](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/977613745634471937)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компа под рукой нет, чтобы нормально разобраться в третьем примере, но это похоже на реализацию "интернизации", которая есть, например, для строк в c#, да и не только для них и не только в c#.

В общем тут (по крайней мере в первых двух примерах точно) смысл в том, что когда вы создаёте новый кортеж класс Intern пытается вам выдать готовый кортеж, если он уже есть у него в словаре, а не создавать новый кортеж. Таким образом, при создании второго одинакового кортежа вы экономите память - новый кортеж не создаётся, выдаётся ссылка на уже лежащий в словаре.

Плюсы тут очевидны, но есть и минусы - если кортеж вам больше не нужен, вы должны вручную как-то определить, что вам не нужны и все его копии и удалить его из этого словаря. Сборщик мусора за вас это не сделает. Хотя в случае с lru_cache всё не так просто, со временем ссылки могут выпадать из его внутреннего словаря и тогда память может несколько почиститься.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!